# JPG re-compression and posting of example pictures

Tags: discussion

Sometimes when I look at a picture someone has posted to illustrate a problem that they have, I wonder if I'm seeing what they are seeing. Has flickr or imagur, etc. re-compressed the image to make it worse than what the person who posted the image originally saw?

Is there a mechanism we could use that would allow folks to post a TIFF or RAW file somewhere so we could see exactly what they are seeing (understanding the possibility of monitor miscalibration)?

Or is this too much of an edge case?

And as far as monitor miscalibration goes, should we do what dpreview does and have a grayscale chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post PNG images, and to my knowledge these are not recompressed

Comment: Looking back at my own question, it probably is way too much of an edge case. Presumably the person posting the question could see how the picture rendered.